# Installing Apache httpd 2.4.x on AIX 7.1 using xlc

Tags: apache, aix, xlc

I am installing apache httpd 2.4.x on AIX 7.1 machine using xlc compiler. Make is successful. But make install is failing with the following error

Making install in modules Making install in aaa rm -f /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-kiran/modules/mod_authn_file.so /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-2.4.25/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=install install mod_authn_file.la /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-kiran/modules/ find: bad status-- /home/u980868/apache/kiran/httpd-kiran/modules/mod_authn_file.so install: File mod_authn_file.so was not found. make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.   Stop. make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.   Stop. make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.   Stop. make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.   Stop.

can someone please help.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, this community is for developers which are writing programs. **For apache support, please call the Apache support .-.**

Comment: We are facing issue while installation. On linux machines we are  able to install it correctly. But we are facing issue on AIX machines. Kindly help.

Comment: https://www.apachelounge.com/